# Is there a way I can aggregate values within a VARIANT column in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregate-functions, variant

I would like to aggregate a VARIANT column while keeping the same structure without breaking it out then compiling again.

for example:

FEES_APPLIED

```
{   "FeesAppliedTotal": {     "Amount": 0.4,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "ReceiptFee": {     "Amount": 0.1,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "ReminderFee": {     "Amount": 0.1,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "TransactionFee": {     "Amount": 0.2,     "Currency": "GBP"   } }
{   "FeesAppliedTotal": {     "Amount": 0.4,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "ReceiptFee": {     "Amount": 0.1,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "ReminderFee": {     "Amount": 0.1,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "TransactionFee": {     "Amount": 0.2,     "Currency": "GBP"   } }
{   "FeesAppliedTotal": {     "Amount": 0.4,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "ReceiptFee": {     "Amount": 0.1,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "ReminderFee": {     "Amount": 0.1,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "TransactionFee": {     "Amount": 0.2,     "Currency": "GBP"   } }
{   "FeesAppliedTotal": {     "Amount": 0.4,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "ReceiptFee": {     "Amount": 0.1,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "ReminderFee": {     "Amount": 0.1,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "TransactionFee": {     "Amount": 0.2,     "Currency": "GBP"   } }
```

the output should be:

```
{   "FeesAppliedTotal": {     "Amount": 1.6,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "ReceiptFee": {     "Amount": 0.4,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "ReminderFee": {     "Amount": 0.4,     "Currency": "GBP"   },   "TransactionFee": {     "Amount": 0.8,     "Currency": "GBP"   } }
```

is this possible?

Comment: The JSON in the top sample would only be valid if it were in different rows or if it were an array in a variant column (or perhaps something else). Are these individual rows? For fields that cannot be summed like "GBP", will they always be the same values or would this produce separate rows like a group by expression?

Comment: yes, the first JSON is 4 separate rows. and the Currency column would have the same value for the same group by key.

Comment: I don't believe you can do this while keeping the data as JSON - but you can probably so this in a SQL statement (i.e. you don't have to convert the JSON into physical columns in a table). It's probably easiest to do this using CTEs e.g. first CTE gets the columns from the JSON, second CTE does the group by using the first CTE result and then finally you convert the result from the second CTE back into JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible. You should parse the JSON to get the values, do the calculations and then rebuild the JSON:

```
select object_agg( key, value ) as result from (
select f.key, object_construct('Amount', sum(f.VALUE:Amount::NUMBER(2,1)), 'Currency', 'GBP' ) value from my_table,
lateral flatten( v ) f
group by f.key);

+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                                                             RESULT                                                                                                              |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| { "FeesAppliedTotal": { "Amount": 1.6, "Currency": "GBP" }, "ReceiptFee": { "Amount": 0.4, "Currency": "GBP" }, "ReminderFee": { "Amount": 0.4, "Currency": "GBP"   }, "TransactionFee": { "Amount": 0.8, "Currency": "GBP" } } |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```